# \textcolor with Arabic and polyglossia highlights whole line

Tags: xetex, color, polyglossia, arabic

I would like to highlight certain phrases in my XeLaTeX document in a different color. The document is completely in Arabic and I'm using `polyglossia` and `xcolor`. My problem is that the color bleeds on to phrases or in this case the line where the highlighting starts, I'd prefer to just have it highlight EXACTLY what I put in the arguments of `\textcolor` as can be seen in the first occurrence of the function in my document.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\definecolor{titlecolor}{rgb}{.25,.25,.25}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Scale=2.0,Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Numbers=Proportional]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\titlefont[Scale=2.0,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\section{الفصل الأول: المقدمة}
نحمده حمداً كثيراً، والصلاة والسلام على نبيه الذي أرسله بالحق بشيراً ونذيراً، هاديًا داعيًا إليه بإذنه وسراجًا منيراً، وعلى آله وصحبه الذين ساروا في نصرة دينه سيرا حثيثًا وبعد:\\[12pt]
فيقول العاجز الحقير الفقير إلى ربه المستجير، أبو عبد الكبير محمد الشهير بعبد الجليل السامرودي -تسامح الله وتجاوز عن جرائمه، وجرائم شيخه الجلية والخفية-: الاختلاف في أئمتنا أهل الحديث خاصة في إتمام البسملة والاكتفاء على لفظ بسم الله فقط في أوائل الأكل والأشربة والتوضيء وغيرها حتى جرى بينهم الاشتهارات ووقع العوام في بحار التردد، والريب والارتياب، بل ضاقت عليهم المسألة بما رحبت. فأردت أن أنقح لك المسألة في جزء بدلائل السنة السنية الصحيحة الصريحة ليتميز بها الحق النجيح والباطل القبيح. وتبصرة لكل رجل بصير سميته: بـ «الغمغمة في سنية التسمية عند الأطعمة وغيرها دون البسملة». أسأل الله سبحانه وتعالى أن يوفقني على الإتمام، وهو المستعان وعليه التكلان.\\[12pt]
أقول وبالله أصول وأجول: عليكم -يامعشر أهل العلم خاصة- أن تتيقظوا من مغامات الغفلة، واعلموا أن الله سبحانه وتعالى ما افترض على أحد من عباده إلا الطاعة له ولرسوله، وجعل الذل والصغار على من خالفهما، وجعل الفوز والنجاح لمن اتبع أمرهما ، كما قال عز شأنه:\textcolor{titlecolor}{﴿وَمَنْ يُطِعِ اللهَ وَرَسُولَهُ فَقَدْ فَازَ فَوْزًا عَظِيمًا﴾}\footnote{سورة الأحزاب (آية رقم:71).}.وحذر الناس كل الحذر ممن خالف أمرهما فقال سبحانه عز شأنه: \textcolor{titlecolor}{﴿فَلْيَحْذَرِ الَّذِينَ يُخَالِفُونَ عَنْ أَمْرِهِ أَنْ تُصِيبَهُمْ فِتْنَةٌ أَوْ يُصِيبَهُمْ عَذَابٌ أَلِيمٌ﴾}\footnote{سورة النور (آية رقم: 63).}

\end{document}
```

And here is my output:
[image: Visual Output]

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your minimal example doesn’t compile, because you haven’t defined titlecolor.  It would be useful if you could use a freely available font in your example (e.g., Amiri, in TeX Live).

Comment: I've defined `titlecolor` after choosing the packages. I'll change the fonts.

Comment: `\definecolor{textcolor}  {rgb}{.25,.25,.25}` has to become `\definecolor{titlecolor}{rgb}{.25,.25,.25}` before the example will compile.  And the output doesn’t look like your pictured output.

Comment: Yes, you're right since the font has changed, but the problem remains. Let me update my screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried the `xecolor` package?  It’s meant for bidi.

Comment: No and I have yet to find some decent documentation with TeXdoc regarding it. Do I replace `xcolor` with it or?

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s your example, with `xecolor` instead of `xcolor`, to support bidirectional text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xecolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\definergbcolor{titlecolor}{750000}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Scale=2.0,Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Numbers=Proportional]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\titlefont[Scale=2.0,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\section{الفصل الأول: المقدمة}
نحمده حمداً كثيراً، والصلاة والسلام على نبيه الذي أرسله بالحق بشيراً ونذيراً، هاديًا داعيًا إليه بإذنه وسراجًا منيراً، وعلى آله وصحبه الذين ساروا في نصرة دينه سيرا حثيثًا وبعد:\\[12pt]
فيقول العاجز الحقير الفقير إلى ربه المستجير، أبو عبد الكبير محمد الشهير بعبد الجليل السامرودي -تسامح الله وتجاوز عن جرائمه، وجرائم شيخه الجلية والخفية-: الاختلاف في أئمتنا أهل الحديث خاصة في إتمام البسملة والاكتفاء على لفظ بسم الله فقط في أوائل الأكل والأشربة والتوضيء وغيرها حتى جرى بينهم الاشتهارات ووقع العوام في بحار التردد، والريب والارتياب، بل ضاقت عليهم المسألة بما رحبت. فأردت أن أنقح لك المسألة في جزء بدلائل السنة السنية الصحيحة الصريحة ليتميز بها الحق النجيح والباطل القبيح. وتبصرة لكل رجل بصير سميته: بـ «الغمغمة في سنية التسمية عند الأطعمة وغيرها دون البسملة». أسأل الله سبحانه وتعالى أن يوفقني على الإتمام، وهو المستعان وعليه التكلان.\\[12pt]
أقول وبالله أصول وأجول: عليكم -يامعشر أهل العلم خاصة- أن تتيقظوا من مغامات الغفلة، واعلموا أن الله سبحانه وتعالى ما افترض على أحد من عباده إلا الطاعة له ولرسوله، وجعل الذل والصغار على من خالفهما، وجعل الفوز والنجاح لمن اتبع أمرهما ، كما قال عز شأنه:\textxecolor{titlecolor}{﴿وَمَنْ يُطِعِ اللهَ وَرَسُولَهُ فَقَدْ فَازَ فَوْزًا عَظِيمًا﴾}\footnote{سورة الأحزاب (آية رقم:71).}.وحذر الناس كل الحذر ممن خالف أمرهما فقال سبحانه عز شأنه: \textxecolor{titlecolor}{﴿فَلْيَحْذَرِ الَّذِينَ يُخَالِفُونَ عَنْ أَمْرِهِ أَنْ تُصِيبَهُمْ فِتْنَةٌ أَوْ يُصِيبَهُمْ عَذَابٌ أَلِيمٌ﴾}\footnote{سورة النور (آية رقم: 63).}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of the above code]

The documentation is in a brief README file.  Here, I’ve just replaced `xcolor` with `xecolor` and changed the color definition in your preamble to `\definergbcolor{titlecolor}{750000}`, and in the document I changed `\textcolor{titlecolor}{…}` to `\textxecolor{titlecolor}{…}`.